# How can I help a long-nailed person type?

Tags: keyboard, typing

My mom has long nails and she is **PROUD** of them. Sometimes she needs to do something at the computer. When it concerns typing text, she does that using two pencils holding them in two hands. Or sometimes - one pencil in one hand. This method of typing is very slow and tiresome.

So... the question is - is there any method of fast and convenient typing for long-nailed women? May be some special gadget or special keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this thread : [How do you type with long nails?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071022115009AAPk8v0)

Apparently it's quite possible to type despite long nails and without any mechanical aid such as pencils.

One just has to hold the hands at the right angle and use the pads of the fingers. It seems to take some training, but is then quite efficient (although not as much as when typing with clipped nails).

Comment: It is possible.  All she has to do is make the effort and practice.  One of the ladies at work had nails that where over a centimeter past the tip and she didn't seemed to be able to type pretty fast.

Answer (score 8):

I think your mother needs to make a value judgement as to whether typing or nails are more important to her. You can't always have it both ways in this life. ;)

Comment: ;) She made already. Nails are more important. That's why I serve as a secretary sometimes ;)

Comment: Then I guess you already found the ideal solution, for her... :)

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny, long nails are a status symbol for women. They demonstrate that they don't need to do any manual work. Long nails say that a woman is rich enough to pay others to do manual work for her. Your mother is treating you—her own son—as a servant. That is a pretty shameful thing for her to do. You should have some self-respect and refuse.

Answer (score 4):

Voice recognition system maybe?

Comment: Yep, I thought about that. I even tried one. You need to speak slow and pronounce clearly to have it recognize words well. To me it was annoying to use it...

Comment: How long ago have you tried it? They improved big deal in the last couple of years.

Comment: Also, was it more annoying than having to type with pencils? ;)

Comment: Sure it's annoying to YOU to use because you can type quickly. The point is, does your mother find it more or less annoying than typing with a pencil? 

Also, while it's nice for you to help your mom out by serving as typist (and I'm a mom of a grown-up geek), she won't make the effort to learn to use the voice system or any other new thing until you stop helping her (so much). She raised you to be independent; now you can show her how well it works. =)

Comment: ;) I will try to. Just Russian language is a little bit harder than English to be recognized correctly. And when I stop helping her to work at the PC, she pretends to be offended and stops working at it for a time ;) It is just a leisure time spending for her.

Comment: @FractalizeR, oh, yes, only English is recognized well these days, you might skip trying, it won't work :)

Comment: Yea... We have some recognition systems, but they used to at least incorrectly spell word endings in Russian. And that matters, because endings in Russian reflect case.

Comment: @FractalizeR, I knew that already :)

Answer (score 2):

Long fingernails were quite fashionable back in the days of typing pools  (certainly they were in the 1970s when typing pools were still current technology).  Lots of typists used to do this - I can even remember seeing sitcoms from the era making jokes about people breaking their fingernails while typing.